# UPDATE COM INSERT

Tags: sql

Estou precisando fazer um `update` simples em uma tabela:

```
UPDATE empresas set DISPONIVEL = 's' WHERE pagamento IN (3, 7, 10, 13, 17, 22, 27);
```

Porem na tabela `empresas`, nem todas empresas tem o `pagamento` registrado, então se por exemplo na `empresa 1`, não tiver o `pagamento` = 3, eu precisaria registrar na tabela `empresas`, precisaria registrar a `empresa` com o outro numero de `pagamento`.

Comment: não pode simplesmente fazer um insert antes? dependendo do banco tem comandos para fazer ambas as operações (geralmente conhecida com UPSERT) mas acho melhor inserir antes, tem mais controle e visibilidade sobre o que está sendo feito

Answer (score -2):

Você pode encontrar esse conceito pelo nome de `UPSERT` em alguns artigos.

Se estiver usando MySQL, você pode chegar a isso usando o [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html) que faz a atualização ou a inserção validando pela `primary key` da tabela.

Answer (score -2):

Cria uma `Foreign key` nessa tabela, depois cria uma tabela *EMPRESA_PAGAMENTOS*

| ID_EMPRESA | ID_PAGAMENTO |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 13 |

```
UPDATE EMPRESAS E 
INNER JOIN EMPRESA_PAGAMENTOS EMP ON E.ID_EMPRESA = EMP.ID_EMPRESA
SET DISPONIVEL = 'S' WHERE EMP.ID_PAGAMENTO IN (3, 7, 10, 13, 17, 22, 27)
```